# problem to determine the chromatic polynomial of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, polynomial-math, text-coloring

for a homework graph theory, I'm asked to determine the chromatic polynomial of the following graph

[image]

For the ***Descomposition Theorem of Chromatic Polynomials***. if G=(V,E), is a connected graph and e belong E

```
P (G, λ) = P (Ge, λ) -P(Ge', λ)
```

where Ge denotes de subgraph obtained by deleting de edge e from G  (Ge= G-e) and Ge' is the subgraph obtained by identifying the vertices {a,b} = e

When calculating chromatic Polynomials, i shall place brackets about a graph to indicate its chromatic polynomial. removes an edge any of the original graph to calculate the chromatic polynomial by the method of decomposition.

[image]

```
 P (G, λ) = P (Ge, λ)-P (Ge', λ) = λ (λ-1)^4 - [λ(λ-1)*(λ^2 - 3λ + 3)]
```

But the response from the answer key and the teacher is:

```
P (G, λ) = λ (λ-1)(λ-2)(λ^2-2λ-2)
```

I have operated on the polynomial but I can not reach the solution that I ask .. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting problem but i think you might do better with getting an answer at: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeah but in both pages i can't post any images because im new user.

Comment: Go ahead and open new questions on both sites and i'll edit the questions for you with the images as they are here. Reply here, of course, so I know when the Qs are ready.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33946/problem-to-determine-the-chromatic-polynomial-of-a-graph

Comment: Sounds like you got a great answer. And a good idea to link back to SO for the original question with images. So you're good to go?

Comment: the question was not solved, but it gave me an idea of how to do it, I think I'll close the question

Comment: You can answer your question, don't forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

math.stackexchange.com told me as a way to solve my problem. Here's the solution:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33946/problem-to-determine-the-chromatic-polynomial-of-a-graph

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct, and so is the teacher's  --they are equal.
[By the way, nice picture and explanation.]

An odd-cycle can have no 2-coloring, hence the 5-cycle can
have no 2-coloring, so its chromatic polynomial, f(x),
must have
                x * [x - 1] * [x - 2]

as a divisor.  If you combine your expression for f(x) and
divide out the

```
x * [x - 1]
```

then you'll find that what remains is divisible by [x - 2], and the
quotient is what your teacher wrote.
                                       -Jonathan King

Answer (score 0):

In the book I am following (Graph Theory with Applications - Deo Prentice Hall) it is done differently. Instead of excluding the edge they connect two non-adjacent vertices.

Using this technique I am getting

`P (G, λ) = 2λ(λ-1)^2(λ-2) + 2λ(λ-1)(λ-2)(λ-3) + λ(λ-1)(λ-2)(λ-3)(λ-4)` which is also not equal to either of your results.

[image]